# Risk involved on installing WDS on Domain Controller

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, active-directory

Is there any Risk involved, if we install WDS on Domain Controller ( Windows Server 2008 R2)

Thanks & Regards,

Param

Answer (score 0):

In general it is not recommended to install any third party software on a productive DC. AD is the core of your Microsoft infrastructure and you don't want it to go offline when a 3rd party software on your DC suddenly decides to consume all system resources or simply cause a BSOD.

The only exception to this third party software rule applies to your backup agent and the Anti-Virus.

Comment: Could the person who downvoted this explain why this is not a good answer/advice?

Answer (score 0):

The main concern about [WDS](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772106%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) is that depending on the number of client computers that will connect to it, it can consume a lot of network bandwidth.
If in addition if you plan to store [WIM](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc749478%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) images on this server you'll have to make sure you have enough disk space and performance.
You can find further information in WDS [Optimizing Performance and Scalability](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732088%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) Technet article.

Anyways it's not a best practice to install too many roles on one server especially on domain controllers because of their criticity.

I advise you to install WDS on another server if it's possible.